# Ask specific question to a particular sect?

Tags: discussion, questions

Ask specific question to a particular sect? E.g. asking question to Shias only or asking question to Sunnis only etc.

Is this allowed or not? And if not then why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the site itself is non-denominational, questions pertaining to any and all flavors of Islam are welcome. As long as they're related to the topic of Islam, questions soliciting answers from a *specific* perspective (e.g., Shi'a-only, Hanafi-only, Qur'an-only, etc.) are just as welcome as those which are scoped more generally.  Merely specify in the body of the question which perspective you're seeking an answer from; any answers from an irrelevant perspective can thus be flagged and/or deleted.

Tagging questions by denomination may also be appropriate, however it is unwise to rely on tags alone for specification; as tags can be easily overlooked, the perspective required should still be mentioned in the question body itself.  Otherwise it's likely to solicit answers from anyone.

Comment: I agree with this, it is fine and completely logical enough. But, just a little reminder, the body of the question talking about the perspective is not sufficient, there must be something like **Note:** suffis only, or hanafis only specifically mentioned atleast at the end of the question or in the title.. What do u say?

Comment: Like [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/is-al-arabi-a-sober-sufi-sufi-view) & [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7269/what-is-the-role-of-a-sheikh-in-sufism-sufi-view) but not like [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/who-was-gebansha-pir), tagging alone is not sufficient I guess. What if one doesn't know how to look at tags, then ends up answering innocently then gets downvoted, then gets disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

If the phenomenon in question is obviously unique to a particular sect then a simple tag is more than enough.

We don't explicitly state it's a Python question on SO when it is evident from the code and experts (same thing which we want on this site) quickly check the tags if it's not clear, just to make sure. Plus tags in most cases are the determining factor (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/1309352)

E.g. in the question [Is it true that all the infallibles are destined to receive martyrdom?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10567/3487) the phenomenon under question is unique to the shiite school of belief therefore it does not need to be any more specific within the question body. We are better off not getting answer from a user who actually is not knowledgable enough to discern which sect the phenomenon under question belongs to or read the quesion carefully.

Places where it is *advisable* to state in the question body the denomination and perspective from which an answer is sought is e.g. [What is the ruling of shaking-hands with a non-mahram who is non-Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17640/3487). This question could get different answers based on the perspective so better state at then have the community do the cleaning.'

---

Evidence abound, there are plenty of instance when the perspective sought is clearly stated in the question and tag yet it recieves answers from another perspective.

Comment: -1. "yet it receives answers from another perspective." cuz people who are in leisure venture to answer questions which even they can't handle because **voting in here sucks**, and they're not afraid. **This is NOT SO**. People barely read the whole question, and **tags are easily overlooked at least in Islam.SE.**

Comment: In case, if you have a little problem whether to keep or not to keep the **(Shia View)** in ur question, plz raise a new meta. When you fail to mention that, people think a Sunni is asking about that belief (probably in a criticizing way), and **new users (Sunni) attempt to answer your particular question.** *What if you just let that be dear*. I hope u cope. :)

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser If voting fails to acceptably control non-expert answers on questions targetted at experts, the solution is to fix voting:  Dumbing down questions so the non-experts (who OP isn't even targetting) can understand it is just extra work on the part of the questioner and, quite frankly, makes the questioner look *less* of an expert than he actually is. The *tone* of a question can be a major consideration for how (or even *if*) an *actual expert* actually chooses to *answer the question*.  See also relevant meta discussion http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/88/22

Comment: I get that Mr Gold, but u see the problem with this question, is just mentioning or not mentioning a simple two words within brackets i.e. (Shia View) which this person is not interested in doing so. But, what if as you said, there is very new user out there who is actually an expert but fails to overlook the tags and he attempts to answer the wrong question. Moreover, questions of this sort need to be properly specifying complete details as much as possible about their beliefs, their origins, and whom is the question targeting for. i.e. what I'm saying, just to let that thing be. @goldPseudo

Comment: I'm very much interested in improving the quality of voting in here, but regarding this issue, "***tags are overlooked by new users***" is an universal truth even which you agree up on. So, properly mentioning the target is highly necessary so as not to waste the time of those people. @goldPseudo

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser , My answer is above the line, the one below is a related comment. Those questions are used as relevant example and as long as this discussion can provide a guideline I am not interested in starting another meta that discusses just this. New users or not, they should be knowledgeable enough to answer the question and know whether they should and can (be it in leisure or not). And they should read the question completely. I care less about proposing new and dumb policies here just because users (new or not) do not read the question completely.

Comment: I'm sorry, and I quit. Plz do what ever you feel is good. But, all I just request you is let that be, and don't waste the time of people (new or not). Although I'll be glad to teach them how to use the tags and also how to vote if possible. :)